# angular scope item +1 not returning multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding 1 to a value of zero which returns 1 and bring up the next item in the set which works. However if I click on the ng-click event again I was hoping it adds +1 to the same number returning 2 and then getting the next item, but it doesn't take a look below.

```
App.controller('slideCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {

$scope.item = 0;

    $scope.prev = function() {
        $scope.item = -1;
    }; 

    $scope.next = function() {
        $scope.item = +1;
    };  

});
```

HTML

```
 <a ng-hide="x.Slide ==1" ng-click="prev();">Left Arrow</a>
                <span ng-show="x.Slide ==1"></span>
                <span class="card-Section">{{x.Slide}}/{{count()}}</span>
                <a ng-click="next();">Right Arrow</a>
```

Comment: please note this is a snippet of the whole thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simply logic fault, if you assign it:

```
$scope.item = -1;
```

You're telling the item to be `-1` not to decrement.

To make it work you have to do it:

```
$scope.prev = function() {
    $scope.item--;
}; 

$scope.next = function() {
    $scope.item++;
};
```

**Tip:** I don't know what `count()` is, but for sure you **must not** call the function like this:

```
<span class="card-Section">{{x.Slide}}/{{count()}}</span>
```

It will make several calls in `count()` function.

Comment: Ahh I think you nailed it, on this one.  I just overlooked that one.

Comment: Count is an angular template placeholder where content will load, and yes your solution worked.